# Update Transfered iOS app to another developer account

Tags: ios, transfer

I have transfered ios app to another developer account.  Now,  I have to update the same app. How to achive this in terms of certificate and provisional profiles and itunes dashboard actions.

The code,  certificate,  provisional profiles for my account is with me.

Please help.

Comment: If you have transferred the app to another account then it is no longer anything to do with the certificates or provisioning profiles for your account.  You need to be associated with the new account and have a developer certificate from that new account in order to upload a new version

Comment: Which certificates needed from other developer.  To update the app

Comment: @Paulw11 I have same problem, we are not able to update the app. We need to remove the app from older account then other can be installed

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. Go to iTunesConnect, click on the app you want to transfer and click on "transfer app".

- The app will still be available on the app store during the transfer.

More information is available to go through the Apple Documentation link

- https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f

  Please click on below for more details

  - https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account